# python plot several curves from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot several appliances' temperatures on a plot.

The data comes from the dataframe df below, and I first create the date column as the index.

```
df=df.set_index('Date')

Date                  Appliance      Value (degrees)
2016-07-05 03:00:00   Thermometer    22
2016-08-06 16:00:00   Thermometer .  19
2016-12-07 21:00:00 . Thermometer .  25
2016-19-08 23:00:00 . Thermostat .   21
2016-25-09 06:00:00 . Thermostat .   20
2016-12-10 21:00:00 . Thermometer .  18
2016-10-11 21:00:00 . Thermostat .   21
2016-10-12 04:00:00 . Thermometer .  20
2017-01-01 07:00:00 . Thermostat .   19
2017-01-02 07:00:00 . Thermometer .  23
```

We want to be able to show 2 curves: one for the thermometer's temperatures and one for the thermostat's temperatures with 2 different colours, over time.

```
plt.plot(df.index, [df.value for i in range(len(appliance)]
ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2016-07-05'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-30'))
```

Is ggplot better for this?

I cannot manage to make this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course several ways to plot the data.
So assume we have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ["2016-07-05 03:00:00", "2016-08-06 16:00:00", "2016-12-07 21:00:00", 
         "2016-19-08 23:00:00", "2016-25-09 06:00:00", "2016-12-10 21:00:00", 
         "2016-10-11 21:00:00", "2016-10-12 04:00:00", "2017-01-01 07:00:00", 
         "2017-01-02 07:00:00"]       
app = ["Thermometer","Thermometer","Thermometer","Thermostat","Thermostat","Thermometer",
       "Thermostat","Thermometer","Thermostat","Thermometer"]     
values = [22,19,25,21,20,18,21,20,19,23]  
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : dates, "Appliance" : app, "Value":values})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')  
df=df.set_index('Date')
```

#### Using matplotlib `pyplot.plot()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = df[df["Appliance"] == "Thermostat"]
df2 = df[df["Appliance"] == "Thermometer"]

plt.plot(df1.index, df1["Value"].values, marker="o", label="Thermostat")
plt.plot(df2.index, df2["Value"].values, marker="o", label="Thermmeter")
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.legend()
```

#### Using pandas `DataFrame.plot()`

```
df1 = df[df["Appliance"] == "Thermostat"]
df2 = df[df["Appliance"] == "Thermometer"]

ax = df1.plot(y="Value", label="Thermostat")
df2.plot(y="Value", ax=ax, label="Thermometer")
ax.legend()
```